# synchronize and highlight HTML text to audio

Tags: html, html5-audio

If necessary I can explain in more detail but essentially what I need to do is effect CSS changes to HTML text in sync with an audio track - i.e., highlighting words/phrases in sync with the audio playback. I also need to control the audio playback by clicking on the text. I have good HTML/CSS chops, but I’m not as strong with raw js, so I’m hoping there’s a jQuery approach. I’m hoping someone can steer me in the best direction.

Many thanks in advance,

svs

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For ease of use, I recommend a combination of jQuery and [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) for anything where you want to integrate media with HTML, and visa versa. See this [jsfiddle post](http://jsfiddle.net/thisgeek/At3xg/) for an example.

For the record, should jsfiddle ever disappear, here's the code:

HTML

```
<audio id="greeting" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17154625/greeting.ogg" controls></audio>

<div id="text">
   <span id="w1" class="word" data-start="1.0">Hello</span>,
   and <span id="w2" class="word" data-start="2.0">welcome</span>
   to Stack <span id="w3" class="word" data-start="3.0">Overflow</span>.
   Thank you for asking your question.
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.word {
   color: red;
}
.word:hover, .word.selected {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}​
```

JS

```
var pop = Popcorn("#greeting");

var wordTimes = {
    "w1": { start: 1, end: 1.5 },
    "w2": { start: 1.9, end: 2.5 },
    "w3": { start: 3, end: 4 }
};

$.each(wordTimes, function(id, time) {
     pop.footnote({
        start: time.start,
        end: time.end,
        text: '',
        target: id,
        effect: "applyclass",
        applyclass: "selected"
    });
});

pop.play();

$('.word').click(function() {
    var audio = $('#greeting');
    audio[0].currentTime = parseFloat($(this).data('start'), 10);
    audio[0].play();
});​
```

Comment: Super - thank you very much! I'll have my hands full playing with this ... I hope you'll indulge me if I need to follow up. Cheers!

Comment: p.s. what did you use to generate the voice in the jsfiddle demo?

Comment: On my Mac, I ran `say "Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Thank you for asking your question." -o greeting.ogg`

Comment: Thx again! I was not aware of the system voice options!

Comment: @thisgeek i tried using my own dropbox link using a .mp3 file but its not playing for some reason, any idea why?

Comment: @bouncingHippo Did you try putting the sound file in your [public folder](https://www.dropbox.com/help/16/en)?

Comment: Did you put in wordTimes manually or did you generate them somehow?