# Converting JSON to object, passing key value pairs into function

Tags: javascript, json, html5-audio, popcornjs

Looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746567/1931288, which passes key value pairs into a function, I would like to save the data externally in JSON format.

This is the format required:

```
var wordTimes = {
  "w1": { start: 1, end: 1.5 },
  "w2": { start: 1.9, end: 2.5 },
  "w3": { start: 3, end: 4 }
};

$.each(wordTimes, function(id, time) {
  pop.footnote({
    start: time.start,
    end: time.end,
    text: '',
    target: id,
    effect: "applyclass",
    applyclass: "selected"
  });
});
```

What I am trying to do is parse the JSON data to achieve a similar format. Is there a convenient way to do this?

```
var wordTimes = jQuery.parseJSON('{"id": "w1", "time": {"start":1, "end":3}}');
```

After parsing the data, I am not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the parsed data? If not, what does the data look like with two or more ids?

Comment: The two formats are different, this example should get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/KuQpm/