# How to play only some part of an audio file in android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

seekTo of MediaPlayer class helps in fixing the starting point. How to set the end point? There doesn't appear to be any method available in MediaPlayer class. For e.g., I want to play only the part from 3 to 6 seconds of a 10sec total media. I do see a solution in the form of setting up sleep timer and interrupting the MediaPlayer. Any other better solution available?

Comment: Honestly, the best solution is to simply [cut up the file](http://cut-mp3.com/). Active waiting and sleep solutions aren't going to be particularly accurate and will result in audible artifacts. The `MediaPlayer` simply doesn't support that functionality.

Comment: If you ask, answer or do something.. Its not very nice to make people response (thats what happens when you ask) and do not give any feedback.

Comment: @eyyo, thank you for your response but I'm struggling to understand your code.  I don't know where the end time is set and how it solves the problem I have stated. I'm still searching answer for my problem.  I found a html5 + javascript based solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743683/synchronize-and-highlight-html-text-to-audio but wondering how to use that in a native android application. I'm looking for a solution where text in WebView is highlighted in sync with audio.  I'm new to android and web development.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little bit late :) but here is how i solve my problem

```
private void singlePlayAudio(int start, int duration) {
    // duration = end_part - start_part;

    //in my case i need to pause
    //if other players are playing
    pauseMainPlayer();
    twoMediaPlayersPause();

    final boolean isPlaying = singleMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    if (isPlaying) {
        singleMediaPlayHandler.removeCallbacks(singleAudioThread);
        singleMediaPlayer.pause();
        singleMediaPlayer.seekTo(start);
    }
    singleAudioThread = () -> {
        singleMediaPlayer.pause();
        singleMediaPlayer.seekTo(start);
        autoViewPagerScroller();
    };
    singleMediaPlayer.seekTo(start);
    singleMediaPlayer.start();
    singleMediaPlayHandler.postDelayed(singleAudioThread, duration);
}
private final Handler singleMediaPlayHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
private  Runnable singleAudioThread;
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a sleep timer, but it may be easier to just use a separate thread. This way you don't have to worry as much about what your UI thread is doing, or interrupting it.

Just use [`getCurrentPosition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition%28%29) in a threaded loop to monitor the playback time. When it gets to the target "end" time, just `stop()` it. Adding a sleep delay to the thread is a good idea, too. You don't need to check it as fast as the loop can run, maybe 5-10 times per second should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t find the answer for that you could try a work around solution using a webview that opens a html5-JS web site.

Here is an uncomplete quick example. (use the jsfiddle code)

http://jsfiddle.net/mNPCP/5/

```
<audio id="audio2" 
   preload="auto" 
   src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg" >

   <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>

<script>
  myAudio=document.getElementById('audio2');
  myAudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    this.currentTime = 12;
    this.play();
  });
</script>
```

[From this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029509/html-5-audio-play-file-at-certain-time-point)

This is not the best solution but maybe can help on something..

Good luck!