# Preventing auto-play for html5 audio synchronized to text

Tags: html, audio, text, synchronized, autoplay

I managed to get synchronized and highlighted html text with audio working from this posting:
[synchronize and highlight HTML text to audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743683/synchronize-and-highlight-html-text-to-audio)
(thanks a million!!)

but I can't figure out how to prevent it from auto-playing when I load the page. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume You have checked the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/At3xg/) from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746567/2151050)

on `line 20` remove (javascript tab):

```
pop.play();
```

As simple as that! here's an [forked example](http://jsfiddle.net/jtYre/)